# How can I get String in Django model field and make sure if it is unique

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This question already has answers here:
How to create a GUID/UUID in Python (8 answers)
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 8 mins ago.

(Private feedback for you)

I am generating a string using below technique but one thing I just want be sure of is that uniqueness of the string. will be a great help if anybody evaluate and suggest if there is a better way of getting a unique string.

```
models.py
import random
import string

def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(13))

class Orders(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=13,
            default=random_string_generator,
            editable=False,
            unique=True)
    
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=13,
                       default=random_string_generator,
                       editable=False,
                       unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be made to check if any object has the same string and you can use a loop to do so.
Something like this:

```
def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.digits):
    while True:
        string = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(13))
        if (Orders.objects.filter(token=string).count() == 0 and Orders.objects.filter(identifier=string).count() == 0:
            break
    return string
```